# Get property default value on class initialize

Tags: c#

Let's say we have some class `CarsBase`

```
public class CarsBase
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Then we have some other class `Toyota`

```
public class Toyota : CarsBase
{
    public EngineType EngineType { get; set; }
}
```

Then we are initializing our class instance by using object initializer like so:

```
var myVar = new Toyota()
{
    // DisplayName = "", ← We could do this by our hands, but can it be done automatically?
    EngineType = EngineType.UZ
}
```

**Question:** Is there any way to fill `CarsBase`'s `DisplayName` property automatically on object initialize?

Like, if I had several more car classes (`BMW`, `Suzuki` , etc.), each is extending `CarsBase` and as a result have `DisplayName` property in each class.

Comment: Create [a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) for your classes and set default values.

Comment: I have class that contains a lot of properties (like 300 or more in a total), each property is a custom type (class) with it own properties, and only the last level children are actual simple data types. 

Imagine this as a kind of tree structure of `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` properties.

So you think there is no other solution than creating a constructor?

Comment: Shouldn't `class CarsBase` be `interface Car` or `abstract class Car`? You can override properties, but what is wrong with using `public string DisplayName {get; set; } = string.Empty` in `CarsBase`.

Comment: @martijnn2008 Well I use this for my data structures only. `string.Empty` is not an option, since I want to write each class name into `DisplayName` property using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something that should be done in a constructor.

```
public class Toyota : CarsBase
{
    public Toyota() : base()
    {
        base.DisplayName = "Toyota";
    }
    public EngineType EngineType { get; set; }
}
```

Another option, however less recommended, instead of getting/setting a DisplayName in the same sense, the base class could be changed to use reflection retrieve the classname and use that as the display name:

```
public class CarsBase
{
    public string DisplayName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return this.GetType().Name; 
        }
    }
}
```

This method should just return the "Toyota" from the classname, however would prevent usage of spaces or other special characters. Reflected code such as this also has a tendency to be slower.

Comment: Properties do not require setters to compile, and I agree that using reflection to solve this particular problem is complicated, however it is a solution that returns the classes name without having to specify it in a constructor or through some other clear declaration.

The advantage of this method is that it will return a different name depending on the child class that is instantiated.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. I must use reflection, because I don't know what class name is until it is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor to pass dispay name (or other parameters as required)-

```
Toyota(string displayName)
{
    DisplayName = displayName;
    EngineType = EngineType.UZ;
}
```

Then you can call like this-

```
new Toyota("some display name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property value in the constructor. Something like this:

```
    internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Toyota t = new Toyota() { EngineType = new EngineType() };
        Console.WriteLine(t.DisplayName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class CarsBase
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
public class Toyota : CarsBase
{
    public EngineType EngineType { get; set; }

    public Toyota()
    {
        // set the default Display Name
        // that way you don't have to set it everytime
        this.DisplayName = "Oh what a feeling!";
    }
}
public class EngineType { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done during the initialization stage of object  where constructor is fired . I have created two classes 
* one for holding enum constant value for engine_Types --> EngineType

- one for explaining the inheritance,Constructor-Chaining, creating an instance of class which is an object----> CarsBase

[pre]

```
    namespace stacketst
     {

    public class CarsBase
     {
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
          public CarsBase()
          {
    //called when CarBase object is initialized
     DisplayName = "Base Car";

     }
    }

     public class Toyota : CarsBase
     {
    //getters , setters called as properties in C#         
     public int number_of_wheels { get; set; }
    public double fuel_capacity { get; set; }
    public string engine_type { get; set; }

     public Toyota() //called when an instance of Toyota is created
     {
    //assinging value to this property calls set 
    fuel_capacity = 4.2; 
    number_of_wheels = 4; 
    engine_type = EngineType.name_engines.UZ.ToString(); 
   }     
   }

     public class TestClass
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        //when below line is executed,constructor is fired & the initialization of variable inside constructor takes place    

    var myVar = new Toyota();
  Console.WriteLine(myVar.DisplayName);
     }
    }
    }

    namespace stacketst
        {
     public class EngineType
    {
     //enums to hold constants, common for any Car Class
         public enum name_engines 
    { 

    V12, V10, V8, V6, UZ        
     };
     }
    }
```

[/pre]

Comment: Well `enums` are just for example purposes, actually there are a lot of tree-alike data structures with user-defined data types, each extending base class (that contains some fields that should be in every class that extends base class). I couldn't use `DisplayName = "Base Car";` in my base class because I need to generate that `DisplayName` sort of "dynamically". I use reflection for this purpose.